# Download file vaadin

Tags: java, file, web-applications, arrays, vaadin

I made a taable which has its data source set to a BeanItemContainer.  Each bean has a name (String) and a byte[] which holds a file converted to a byte[].  I added a button to each row which is suppose to download the file by first converting it to a pdf.  I am having trouble implementing the downloading part here is the code relating:

```
public Object generateCell(Table source, Object itemId,
                Object columnId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Beans p = (Beans) itemId;

            Button l = new Button("Link to pdf");
            l.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    try {
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(p.getName() + ".pdf");
                        out.write(p.getFile());
                        out.close();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            l.setStyleName(Reindeer.BUTTON_LINK);

            return l;
        }


    });
```

So getFile gets the byte array from the bean

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Vaadin 7 you can use [FileDownloader](http://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.beta7/docs/api/com/vaadin/server/FileDownloader.html) extension as described here: https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/2864064

Instead of using a clicklistener you would need to extend the button instead:

```
Button l = new Button("Link to pdf");
StreamResource sr = getPDFStream();
FileDownloader fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(sr);
fileDownloader.extend(l);
```

To get the StreamResource:

```
private StreamResource getPDFStream() {
        StreamResource.StreamSource source = new StreamResource.StreamSource() {

            public InputStream getStream() {
                // return your file/bytearray as an InputStream
                  return input;

            }
        };
      StreamResource resource = new StreamResource ( source, getFileName());
        return resource;
}
```

Comment: note: the file must exists before initializes the filedownloader.

Comment: as @SüniÚr mentioned we would need the file before we initialize the file downloader, but that file can be any file and you can later change the resource if you want by saying fileDownloader.setFileDownloadResource(newResource) (if in case somebody needs this)

Answer (score 3):

Generated columns creation is well described in [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html), one correction to your code would be to check columnId or propertyId to ensure you create a button in right column - currently it seems you return a button for any column.

Something like this:

```
    public Object generateCell(CustomTable source, Object itemId, Object columnId)
    {
        if ("Link".equals(columnId))
        {
            // ...all other button init code is omitted...
            return new Button("Download");
        }
        return null; 
    }
```

To download a file:

```
    // Get instance of the Application bound to this thread
    final YourApplication app = getCurrentApplication();
    // Generate file basing on your algorithm
    final File pdfFile = generateFile(bytes);
    // Create a resource
    final FileResource res = new FileResource(pdfFile, app);
    // Open a resource, you can also specify target explicitly - 
    // i.e. _blank, _top, etc... Below code will just try to open 
    // in same window which will just force browser to show download
    // dialog to user
    app.getMainWindow().open(res);
```

More info on how to deal with resources can be found in [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.resources.html).